# Save JSON in MongoDb with Sails.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js

What I want to do is to create my DataBase from an external API, firstly I create a function `loadData(req, res){}` in my DBController, this function loads the data in JSON format from the API.

What I want to do now is to save this returned JSON within my mongoDB, I don't know how. How can I do that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you have sails-mongo adapters added in the module otherwise use,
    `npm install sails-mongo --save`
2. Define a connection in config/connections.js. You can make it a default connection under config/models.js if you are not using other database.
3. Then, you would have to create a Model with definitions similar to the content of the JSON that the external API is returning.

For eg. if the external API is returning.

```
[{
 attribute1: '<value>',
 attribute2: '<value>',
 attribute3: '<value>'
}]
```

You would want to create a Model under /api/models called Model.js like below,

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
     attribute1: {type: 'integer'},
     attribute2: {type: 'string'},
     attribute3: {type: 'datetime'}
 }
};
```

Refer to [this](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Models.html) to get more idea on creating a model.

4. Then in your controller you can just do,

   ```
   var externalJSON = <API result JSON>;
   Model.create(externalJSON)
   .exec(function(err, user){ 
      //Processing 
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks, the externalJSON contains some attributes that I wont use in my DB, e.g if I create a model with juste attribute1&2, Will my model be creatd even if it dosen't match externalJSON ?

Comment: you can just remove the unwanted attributes from externalJSON before Mode.create. Try lodash for arrays. Read basics of Models here : http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Models.html

Answer (score 2):

If the JSON represents an array of records that match the structure of your db, then all you need to do is load the file and save the contents

```
var data = require('./datafile.json')
MODEL.create(data).exec(function(err,result){/*...*/})
```